# bootstrap collapse bar turns transparent when window is reduced

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

im having issues with my bootstrap responsive background.

as seen below, when my window is reduced to simulate a mobile screen size, my dropdown becomes transparent.

[image: navbar]

this is my code, which was copied from the bootstrap sample websites, the only change i made was the links.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pages">Pages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#extensions">Extensions</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <div class="navbar-right">
            <p style="color:#fff;">some text</p>
          </div>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
</div>
```

[EDIT]
i have this in my header

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta name="description" content="">
     <meta name="author" content="">
```

Comment: Did you include <meta> tag to support device width and device height?

Comment: i updated my post and included my `<head>`, and yes i have meta tag.

Comment: Which version of Firefox you are using? Earlier versions of Firefox and IE are not supported.

Answer (score 58):

This happens when you lock the navbar's height. Check CSS and change:

```
height: 50px;
```

into this:

```
min-height: 50px;
```

Comment: I have the same problem but have not fixed navbar's height -- it's still the same `min-height: 50px;` the Bootstrap CSS defaults to.

Comment: I don't know what css/style you are using. However, the problem wasn't in the bootstrap css, it was in the personal css. Try using `height: auto !important;` for your navbar's `div`, to check if you are modifing the height somehow.

Comment: Thank you! Corrected my problem.

Comment: I love how 6 years later, this easy fix you provided is still helping people.  I was going nuts trying to figure out what change I made at some point that resulted in the transparent menu we're all now familiar with.  A little searching and I found your answer which did the trick perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: indeed this works. 1) in my case absolute height was set because of different @media screen sizes on custom CSS - it was applied to .navbar class - changed it as suggested here 2) background color will still be transparent, I guess, but because navbar will change size dynamically, it will look like it's the navbar's background - otherwise specifying .navbar-collapse background as in other answers also works - if the dynamic resize effect of the .navbar itself is not desirable....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i resolved the problem by adding a css property `position: relative;` in the nav div :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top>
```

became in:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="position: relative;">
```

Comment: Similar to my comment in the above response, I have the same issue and my `navbar` defaults to `position: relative;` already in the Bootstrap CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this. Adding a background style to the `.navbar-collapse` element...

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Becomes

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="background:black">
```

This seemed to fix the problem for me, hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the next line in style.css

```
.navbar-collapse{ 
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me. But when I gave my `navbar` a significantly higher z-index like `z-index: 9999;`, the transparency disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the background color of the .icon-bar.
I had set the background of the navbar to white so that was my issue.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" style="color: black">
            <span class="sr-only ">{% trans "Toggle Navigation" %}</span>
            <span class="icon-bar grey_dark_l_bg"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar grey_dark_l_bg"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar grey_dark_l_bg"></span>
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue this way:

```
.navbar {
  min-height: 85px;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add background in navbar li a, this sample CSS code:

```
.navbar li a, .navbar .navbar-brand {
      color: #fff !important;
      background-color: #08A2FA;
      line-height: 1.42857143 !important; /* this for line in desktop mode */
  }
```